# Run a system command as sudo from R?

Tags: r

Sometimes this works, sometimes not. It seems to depend on whether the system needs to prompt for a password. The more general question would be: is there a way for the user to provide input to a shell command from within R?

```
system('sudo npm install gitbook -g')
```

Note that my specific case is trying to install a node.js module. However, I think you can replicate it using a more trivial command.

```
system('sudo mkdir testdir')
```

Please note that this will sometimes work depending on whether `sudo` requires you to re-enter a password. Thanks.

Comment: This is not a general solution, but you could rely on `gksudo` (a graphical interface for sudo).

Comment: I suggest taking a look at `man sudo`, the -A option may work for you.

Comment: How are you running R?  In my terminal I get prompted for my password if I need it when running sudo through `system`

Comment: I am running R through R Studio. I think that if I authenticated recently (say in the Terminal) then I do not get prompted for a password. Most of the time I do which is why this feature doesn't work. It is not critical, more for convenience. If anyone knows some other package that does something similar that would be helpful. I scanned devtools and installR (but this is really for Windows) and don't see anything helpful.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I can suggest two different solutions:

1. Use `gksudo`, which will prompt the user for a password in a graphical interface. Here is how it works in practice:

   `system('gksudo ls')`

   - PRO:

     - It is secure, you don't have to handle the password yourself.
     - ....
   - CONS:

     - it won't work without a graphical interface.
     - `gksudo` was installed by default with linux brands I have tried, but YMMV: maybe some users won't have it.
     - ....
2. Ask for the user password in `R`, and supply it with the proper `sudo` options: `-k` to always ask for the password, and `-S` to accept the password from the standard input. Here is how it works in practice:

   `system('sudo -kS ls',input=readline("Enter your password: "))`

   - PRO:

     - It does not rely on any other program.
     - ....
   - CONS:

     - I don't like the idea that a password gets manipulated by `R`: it looks like a bad idea.
     - ....

Other than that, I am not aware on any way to interactively communicate with a program started from `R`.

Answer (score 8):

Just to build up on @Jealie's response. I believe 1. Won't work in new versions of ubuntu.

But we can let Rstudio handle the password:

```
system("sudo -kS ls", input = rstudioapi::askForPassword("sudo password"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the `gksudo` utility mentioned in [@jealie's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23188091/7196903) is not maintained anymore (and thus missing from Ubuntu 18.04 onwards), one has to rely on `pkexec` instead as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1067364/622358):

```r
system("pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY ls")
```

The same command using R's newer [`system2()`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/system2.html) function:

```r
system2(command = "pkexec",
        args = "env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY ls",
        stdout = TRUE,
        stderr = TRUE)
```

To run multiple commands in sequence with only a single password prompt, combine this with `sudo` and `bash -c '...'`:

```r
system2(command = "pkexec",
        args = paste0("env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY bash -c ",
                      "'sudo mkdir somedir; sudo ls -1l; sudo rm -R somedir'"),
        stdout = TRUE,
        stderr = TRUE)
```