# Is there an R function to change file ownership?

Tags: r, linux, chown

How could I change the ownership of files from R? I suppose I could use `system` and call `chown` directly against a string, but I am wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: Some system related functions are `Sys.*` (example `Sys.chmod()`) But there is no one for `chown` in base.

Comment: You can type the command into `?system`, but you'll have to cater it to the current OS, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was already mentioned in the comments, the function `Sys.chown()` does not exist. I have written a function that does the job for me. Compared to other functions of the type `Sys.*`, this one has the disadvantage that `chown` requires `sudo`. Using `sudo` with R's `system()` does not work, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23186960/4303162) suggests the use of `gksudo`, which works fine for me.

So this is the function definition:

```
Sys.chown <- function(paths, owner = NULL, group = NULL) {

   # create string for user:owner
   if (!is.null(group)) {
      og <- paste0(owner, ":", group)
   } else {
      og <- owner
   }

   # create string with files
   files <- paste(paths, collapse = " ")

   # run command
   system(paste("gksudo chown", og, files))

   invisible()
}
```

The first part creates the string that sets the owner and the group, which should be of the form `owner:group`. However, it is possible to omit one or both of these argument and the function takes care of all the possibilities.

Next comes the part where all the file names that have been supplied to `paths` are put into a single string.

And finally, `system()` is used to do the actual  call of `chown`. `gksudo` will open a dialog window and ask for the password. Unfortunately, one has to type the password every time.

There are several useful options to `chown` and a better implementation of `Sys.chown()` should probably be able to handle some of them.

**Example**

```
system("ls -l")
## total 0
## -rw-rw-r-- 1 user1 user1 0 Jan 21 19:32 test2.file
## -rw-rw-r-- 1 user1 user1 0 Jan 21 19:32 test.file
Sys.chown("test.file", owner = "user2")
Sys.chown("test2.file", group = "user2")
system("ls -l")
## total 0
## -rw-rw-r-- 1 user1 user2 0 Jan 21 19:32 test2.file
## -rw-rw-r-- 1 user2 user1 0 Jan 21 19:32 test.file
Sys.chown("test.file", owner = "user1", group = "user2")
system("ls -l")
## total 0
## -rw-rw-r-- 1 user1 user2 0 Jan 21 19:32 test2.file
## -rw-rw-r-- 1 user1 user2 0 Jan 21 19:32 test.file
Sys.chown(dir(), owner = "user1", group = "user1")
system("ls -l")
## total 0
## -rw-rw-r-- 1 user1 user1 0 Jan 21 19:32 test2.file
## -rw-rw-r-- 1 user1 user1 0 Jan 21 19:32 test.file
```

Comment: afaik, you can use sudo with R's system command, you need to do `sudo -ks <command>` and then submit the password via input. But you should be careful with this, since then the password will be in the command, which could be viewable from ps...etc...