# RStudio- sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

Tags: r, rstudio, putty

I am trying to execute below console commands from RStudio to move to Root from  myuser Rstudio.

```
cmd <- sprintf("sudo su -")
system(cmd)
```

While doing I am getting this reponse:
*"sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified"*

while from putty I am able to execute "*sudo su -*"

Can anyone please suggest the way to execute above console Commands from R/RStudio and 
get resolved the error.

Comment: Because R and RStudio are not designed/setup to execute *interactive* shell commands.

Comment: @r2evans Thanks for the response. So, Is there no way we can trigger  interactive shell commands from R. Needed for a dynamic Shiny App

Comment: Interactive pipes are not really well supported in R. There have been discussions in the past, and unix-based R may be able to [hack it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5561188/3358272) (caveat emptor: old, untested), but I have not found anything (and I've been looking) that supports starting a process and interacting with it (easily). (Are you really trying to provide access to an interactive *shell* (bash) from within a shiny app? Good luck ...)

Comment: Thanks for the information. Yes, Trying to change the permission of files from root through R.Have found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34927257/is-there-an-r-function-to-change-file-ownership   - About gksudo

Comment: I cannot stress this too strongly: caution! A lot of things can go wrong by automating the use of passwordless `sudo`. Really think about what you are trying to accomplish here. I suggest you would be better served by describing what is driving you to want to do that and solicit alternatives that don't punch a gaping whole in security :-)