# Rmarkdown use sudo in bash chunk

Tags: bash, r-markdown

I am trying a simple Rmarkdown doc using the {bash} tag
I need to issue a command with `sudo`
Clearly the markdown engine fails on this task

Any idea how to pass sudo password to a markdown document

Thanks in advance for any help

Follows a reproducible example

````
---

title: "test"

author: "Andrea"

date: "9/15/2020"

output: html_document

---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

text here

```{bash}
ls
```

```{bash}
sudo su
ls
```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/23188091/12957340 (e.g. something like `system("sudo -ks ls", input = password)` <- sudo has a bunch of options that might suit: https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.13/sudo.man.html)

Comment: Not really, I am inside a RMarkdown document. Moreover, I would like to type  sudo pwd only once rather that one time for each chunk where I am using sudo

Answer (score 1):

Possibly I have a solution

Open a terminal and issue any command with sudo: i.e. `sudo pwd`

Than run

```
R -e "rmarkdown::render('test.Rmd',output_file='test.html')"
```